Как удалить всё из консоли вывода в python?
Я хочу сделать игру. Но мне нужно чтобы всё с output стиралось после принта(последнего, их несколько). Пробовал end='\r', flush=True, os.system('cls')(у меня Windows). Что делать?
Код игры:
import keyboard

life = True
a = ["#", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", " ", " ", "#"]
z = 2
h = 0
while life:
    print("###########")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    y = ''
    for i in a:
        y += i
    print(y)
    print("###########")
    if h == 0:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("d"):
            a[z + 4] = "#"
            if z != 0:
                a[z] = " "
            z += 1
        if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
            a[z] = "#"
            if z < 5:
                a[z + 4] = " "
            z -= 1
    h = 0
    if keyboard.is_pressed("d") or keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        h = 1


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Как задать хороший вопрос > https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Вообще cls должен работать, но вот вам ещё 100500+ рецептов для винды: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-can-i-clear-the-interpreter-console

Я пробовал ничто не работает

ну добавил, а игра типа пинг-понга(пока делаю движение одной стенки

Да лучше сразу PyGame учите, чего с консолью мучиться то.

Можно с помощью colorama:

pip install colorama

import keyboard
import os
import time

import colorama

colorama.init()

life = True
a = ["#", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", " ", " ", "#"]
z = 2
h = 0
while life:
    print("###########")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print("#         #")
    print(''.join(a))
    print("###########")
    if h == 0:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("d"):
            a[z + 4] = "#"
            if z != 0:
                a[z] = " "
            z += 1
        if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
            a[z] = "#"
            if z < 5:
                a[z + 4] = " "
            z -= 1
    h = 0
    if keyboard.is_pressed("d") or keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        h = 1
    # добавил для плавности небольшую задержку
    time.sleep(0.1)

    print(colorama.Cursor.UP(11))  # Двигаем курсор вверх на 11

